Should we prefix type on import or export of type defs
For types, should we prefix type when we export the types like,
export type {
  TPromptCommentFieldProps,
};

Or when we import the type,
import { type TPromptCommentFieldProps } from 'test-path';

Or on both.
I've seen that in one repo the type is prefixed when types are imported, and in another repo when types are exposed, and i would like to know the difference and where to add type prefix.

Types are something that will not go into our JavaScript code, transpilers will try to remove them when generating JS.
Transpilers like Babel work (or used to work) on one file at a time. So it is difficult for Babel to tell that in the below import TPromptCommentFieldProps is a type or a value.
import { TPromptCommentFieldProps } from 'test-path';

Read this github comment
This is why the type keyword was added.
The problem does not exist with TypeScript transpiler as it looks at the whole type system together and not individual files.
Similarly for export, if you import something in a file and export it from there, again single file transpilers will not be able to tell the difference between type and value.
import { someType, someFunction } from "someModule";
 
export { someType, someFunction };

The whole intent with which import type and export type were introduced was that most users should not have to think about them.
This is a github comment from one of the contributors of TS:

The intention is for you not to use import type unless you need to. If you don’t have a specific need for type-only imports, you could consider them a stylistic choice.

Your IDE will try to warn you (or even fix things for you) if you are writing code where you might cause a problem like this. This usually would happen when you have isolatedModules flag enabled in tsconfig. It will try to warn you that you are writing code that might be incorrectly interpreted by single file transpilers.
So it will come down to style and need whether you write type with your export and import. If things break, then you have to. If you want to be more explicit in what you import/export, then you have to.
